# JS Code: Comments

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im looking at this piece of code from W3 Schools

```
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}
</script>
```

I know what it does (opens and closes a drop down nav bar), but i dont know what each line of code means / how it does it. I was wondering if anyone here would be kind enough to comment/annotate each line of code with what its doing so i can further understand it and learn from it.

thanks

Comment: _...wondering if anyone here would be kind enough to ..._ SO is not a "comment my code site"....Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask.

Comment: @bub no need to be rude, its quite obviously his first question on SO. just point him in the direction of the help center and explain what he did wrong.

Comment: I understand, im learning web languages and im doing pretty well. Mainly learn by just reading code and it's comments. 

I don't understand how this piece of code works and i cant find it, or anything similar commented anywhere so i thought id post here. 

for someone that fully understands it would only a minute and would help others like me!

Comment: @MasterYoda no need to tell me what to do. Do you see I've posted the link to the tour?

Comment: You should look up the JS functions used and see what they are doing: `.classList.toggle`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, etc. Also, the HTML is relevant to understanding the functionality (for example the elements `#myDropdown` and `.dropbtn`)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown

^Thats the HTML. Thanks man. 

@bub i know im in the wrong place, i just didnt know where else to ask. Didn't think it would be a big deal, sorry

Comment: It may be useful to add breakpoints to the code in your browser while you run it, and step through the code so you can see what happens to the DOM at each step

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

there are actually two things happening here

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown")
```

here document refers to the entire html(DOM) page. [getElementById](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) is a function natively avilable in DOM this piece of code finds the HTML element by with ID myDropdown

```
classList.toggle("show");
```

classlist is element property which contains list of it current classes. This would change this elements class to show

```
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
```

whenever the window is clicked execute this function. Now based on previous code i would leave it as excercise to you understand the below code
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

```
var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
  openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
   }
  }
 }
}
```

i would recommend you to try to out other sites to learn and use stack overflow only when you are stuck at problems you cannot solve. I would recommend this site [codecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/) and try searching online. there is load of articles online. And good luck with your learning